# C++ Type Aliasing Const Issue

Tags: c++, c++11, types, constants, alias

I have this following code:

```
using ccStr = char*;

class Tt {
private:
    const char* tmp;

public:
    const ccStr & str() {
        return tmp;
    }
};
```

But the issue is that "const ccStr" gets evaluated to "char* const" which is basically the reason why tmp can't bind to the return type.
I don't really understand why the const gets moved...
How can I solve this without changing the ccStr type aliasing ?

Comment: `std::add_pointer<std::add_const<std::remove_pointer<ccStr>::type>::type>::type` ? :)

Comment: @Jarod42 ouch. Too bad it's the actual answer :p

Comment: In C++14 one could do this: std::add_pointer_t<std::add_const_t<std::remove_pointer_t<ccStr>>>. lol. But this still looks awful. :S :)

Comment: That'll teach you not to hide pointers behind typedefs :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const ccStr` is a const pointer, `const char *` is a pointer pointed to a const char

```
return const_cast<const ccStr >(tmp);
```

Comment: Ah, I understand :). I guess @Jarod42 also answered my last question how solve the construct into a cons char pointer xD.